# XPages validateExpression not working

Tags: xpages

I want to test if the user has entered any character or digit in the pattern ####-##-###-####

My expression is ^(\w){4}-(\w){2}-(\w){3}-(\w){4}$ and seems to work in online testers, but not in my validateExpression!

Any ideas?

Here is my code (getComponentValye is my own function to get a value) ...

```
<xp:inputText id="nsn" value="#{ddsURFQCI.NSN}">
   <xp:this.validators>
    <xp:validateExpression>
     <xp:this.expression><![CDATA[#{javascript:getComponentValue("nsn").match(new RegExp("^(\w){4}-(\w){2}-(\w){3}-(\w){4}$", "i"))}]]></xp:this.expression>
     <xp:this.message><![CDATA[#{javascript:"NSN must match the pattern ####-##-###-####. (" + getComponentValue("nsn") + ")"}]]></xp:this.message>
     </xp:validateExpression>
   </xp:this.validators>
</xp:inputText>
<xp:message id="message1" styleClass="error" for="nsn"></xp:message>
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you never accept an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my expression to this and it worked ... ^[A-Za-z0-9]{4}-[A-Za-z0-9]{2}-[A-Za-z0-9]{3}-[A-Za-z0-9]{4}$